# Assign EditText a value but display the Hint

Tags: java, android-layout

Can we assign EditText a value say 0 and when the app starts it should show the Hint and not the value but it should be assigned to that EditText

```html
//XML file 
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/amt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amt_view"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Whole Amt"
        android:text="0"
        android:padding="10dp" /
```

Comment: No. The hint is displayed only when the text is blank.

Comment: OKK..so there isn't any alternative to assign a default value and also to display the hint!

Comment: No. Put the default value in a String constant and use it as needed. You might use the `android:tag` property.